# Swift NSImage to CGImage

Tags: cocoa, swift, nsimage

How can I convert a NSImage to CGImage in Swift? In Objective-C I did it like this:

```
- (CGImageRef)CGImage {
    NSData *imageData = self.TIFFRepresentation;
    CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)imageData, NULL);
    CGImageRef maskRef =  CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);
    return maskRef;
}
```

Now I tried with:

```
extension NSImage {
    var CGImage: CGImageRef {
    get {
        let imageData = self.TIFFRepresentation
        let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFDataRef, nil)
        let maskRef = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, UInt(0), nil)
        return maskRef;
    }
    }
}
```

I can't compile, I'm getting the error: `Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments'` at the line `let maskRef ...`

Answer (score 38):

Here's what I'm using to convert NSImage to CGImage:

```
let image = NSImage(named:"image")
if let image = image {
    var imageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
    let imageRef = image.cgImage(forProposedRect: &imageRect, context: nil, hints: nil)
}
```

Comment: You can pass `nil` for `proposedRect` and get the same result.

Comment: You should use `CGRect(origin: .zero, size: image.size)` instead of `CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)`

Answer (score 19):

Swift 5 code :-

```
if let image = NSImage(named: "Icon"){
    let cgImage = image.cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Ah, I found the solution. It's because in Swift you only the an unmanaged object (I just did not really understand, what this means). But this code now works:

```
extension NSImage {
    var CGImage: CGImageRef {
    get {
        let imageData = self.TIFFRepresentation
        let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFDataRef, nil).takeUnretainedValue()
        let maskRef = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, UInt(0), nil)
        return maskRef.takeUnretainedValue();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Right. It's from Apple's book: `When Swift imports APIs that have not been annotated, the compiler cannot automatically memory manage the returned Core Foundation objects. Swift wraps these returned Core Foundation objects in an Unmanaged<T> structure. All indirectly returned Core Foundation objects are unmanaged as well.`

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C.” iBooks. https://itunes.apple.com/ru/book/using-swift-cocoa-objective/id888894773?l=en&mt=11

Comment: what is takeUnretainedValue? there is no such thing on swift.

Comment: `takeUnretainedValue()` isn't available in Swift 5 (the code executes as expected by simply omitting it).

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 4.0, XCode 9.2:

```
extension NSImage {
    @objc var CGImage: CGImage? {
       get {
            guard let imageData = self.tiffRepresentation else { return nil }
            guard let sourceData = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFData, nil) else { return nil }
            return CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(sourceData, 0, nil)
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very similar to the solution provided almost one year before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62298762/1974224. Can you add details on why this answer is different from that one?

Comment: @Cristik its more error-safe and shorer

Answer (score 1):

A Swift 5 implementation:

```
extension NSImage {
    var CGImage: CGImage {
        get {
            let imageData = self.tiffRepresentation!
            let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFData, nil).unsafelyUnwrapped
            let maskRef = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, Int(0), nil)
            return maskRef.unsafelyUnwrapped
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Care to be taken when using `unsafelyUnwrapped`. Even Apple has a big red warning on the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1641793-unsafelyunwrapped) page for this feature.

Comment: And also you're force unwrapping `tiffRepresentation`, which can lead to crashes in case of nil values.