# How can I get a CGImage from my XCode assets catalog

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, cgimage

I am working on an OSX project in XCode.  I have added an image set to my assets catalog in XCode.  It's called 'Foo'.

How can I get a CGImage from it?

It seems to be very simple to get an NSImage from it:

```
let image = NSImage(named: "Foo")
```

...but not a CGImage which is what I need.

Specific set up: XCode 7.1 on OSX 10.11 El-Capitan coding in Swift 2.1 importing Cocoa and MetalKit

Edit: A few people have pointed out how to convert an NSImage to a CGImage via the CGImageForProposedRect method.  I was hoping to avoid the NSImage altogether because it seems like a wasteful intermediate step.  But perhaps this is the only way to access your image asset?  If anyone knows a way to avoid the NSImage conversion that would be great, otherwise I guess the accepted answer is the best way.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595908/swift-nsimage-to-cgimage

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since OS X 10.6, `NSImage` has had method `CGImageForProposedRect(_:context:hints:)`. You can pass `nil` for all parameters. Thus:

```
let nsImage = NSImage(named: "foo")
let cgImage = nsImage?.CGImageForProposedRect(nil, context: nil, hints: nil)
```

Comment: Any idea for iOS? NSImage is only on OSX

Comment: @JCutting8 `return UIImage(named: "yourName")?.cgImage`